# macos fatal error: sys/_types/_int8_t.h: No such file or directory #include <sys/_types/_int8_t.h>

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, clang, homebrew

I recently updated the system macOS Mojave 10.14 and faced the following trouble. I'm not going to projects with using ++ through gcc (my version 8.2) and clang (7.0). The problem is that the program, as I understand it, does not find the standard libraries and gives all the errors like this one :

```
/usr/local/bin/g++-8 -I//Users/MyNames/Desktop myFile.cpp -MyFinalFile -std=c++2a
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/lib/gcc/8/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0/8.2.0/includ e/stdint.h:9,
from builddest.cpp:1:
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/lib/gcc/8/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0/8.2.0/includ e-fixed/stdint.h:27:10:fatal error: sys/_types/_int8_t.h: No such file or directory

    #include <sys/_types/_int8_t.h>
```

Depending on the included header files, I get different errors.On the internet I found some tips, such as :
reinstall XCode (my installed Version 10.0 (10A255) ), install command lines tools - I reinstalled, but nothing helped. In XCode everything works fine. My system is mac mini 2012, macOS 10.14 . Before the upgrade everything worked perfectly.I will be happy for any help
p.s.
If you don’t add any dependencies at all, then everything is going perfectly.

Comment: This isn't a standard c++ header, but part of the compile implementation. You are not supposed to include these directly with your code.

Comment: Yes, and I don’t turn it on - I’ve got such a header in my code - #include <stdint.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

The problem is that it can not include unproblematically simple headers, that is, if you change them and instead substitute some #include <string.h> then it still does not compile - there will simply be another error: fatal error:
       'string.h' file not found
#include_next <string.h>
               ^ ~~~~~~~~~

Comment: I don't expect this to be much help, but Give `#include <cstdint>` a try.

Comment: Is `/usr/local/bin/g++-8 -I//Users/MyNames/Desktop myFile.cpp -MyFinalFile -std=c++2a` the compiler command line? It doesn't make much sense. It looks like you're trying to point ann include folder at a cpp file and  I have no clue what `-MyFinalFile` was supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reinstall Homebrew and GCC after the Mojave update. The GCC toolchain is not included in MacOS for many years now. It appears from your `cellar` directory that you are using a Homebrew installed version of GCC.

Please review the [Homebrew documentation](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ) and do a clean install of Homebrew and GCC. Do note that you will still need Xcode Command Line Tools to install and use Homebrew.

Comment: I was helped by this solution for GCC, but it did not help for the clang. That is, the same attempt to build the same program with the help of clang i get error -  fatal error: 
      'string.h' file not found
#include_next <string.h>  Nobody knows what to do in this case  ? I installed the Clang from the official site, and not through brew

Comment: I am guessing that the two different standard libraries have conflicting paths. Unfortunately, I do not use homebrew myself, so I can't assist in what steps to take, but I am able to isolate clang from gcc when installing them using macports which is similar to homebrew.

Comment: Thank you, I will look for a solution in this direction. You helped me a lot